# Large Binary (byte[]) File transfer through WCF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, basichttpbinding

I am trying to build a WCF service that allows me to send large binary files from clients to the service.

However I am only able to successfully transfer files up to 3-4MB. (I fail when I try to transfer 4.91MB and, off course, anything beyond)

**The Error I get if I try to send the 4.91MB file is:**

**Exception Message:** An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:56198/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

**Inner Exception Message:** The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

**Inner Exception Message:** Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Inner Exception Message:** An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

This error occurs at client side as soon as the byte[] file is sent as a method parameter to the exposed service method.

I have a breakpoint at the service method's first line, in case of successful file transfers (below 3MB) that break point is hit and the file gets transferred. However in this case as soon as the method is called, the error comes. The breakpoint in the service is not hit in case of this error.

I am going to paste my  sections of my Service Web.config and Asp Page (Client) Web.config. If you also require the code that send the file and accepts the file, let me know, I'll send that as well.

**Service Web.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="01:01:00"
      openTimeout="01:01:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedRequest"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>        
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DragDrop.Service.ServiceBehavior" name="DragDrop.Service.Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="DragDrop.Service.IService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DragDrop.Service.ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client (Asp.net page) Web.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646"
         messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
         <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
               realm="">
               <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debuggingBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:56198/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference.IService"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="debuggingBehaviour" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: sorry was editing (some how my service config was not showing up ....) do still need any c# code ...???

Comment: I'm resolved whit this fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998927/how-do-i-upload-large-25mb-files-to-a-web-service

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*(While I agree that [streaming transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx) would be preferrable, the below should make it work without any other changes)*

You also need to increase the maximum message length in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will set the maximum message length to 400 MB (parameter is in kB). Check [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks ... its working ... I just tested a 30MB file, and it is working, I'll do a test of 1-2GB and then see how it goes, but for now, my question is answered .... Thanks a lot.

Comment: For 1-2GB I would seriously consider looking at the streaming capabilities, rather than using a `byte[]`. For one thing, the .NET framework has trouble even *allocating* arrays that size, let alone transmitting them.

Comment: I didnt get that. You mean should i be transferring files in chunks (and each chunk through the streaming as we just did above for 30MB). And then when all chunks have reached the server, then join them together .... would that work, or is their any better way of doing that?

Comment: or u mean the way explained in the link u shared above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Comment: Not meaning to hijack this answer, but I added an answer showing just that :-) Basically, you "return" a `Stream` instead of a `byte[]`. Good luck!

Comment: @Jakob: no problem. I decided to not go out of my way to rehash your and Nick's answer, so I just added a link that at least pointed out the possibility :)

Comment: My Dear God... ¿How many times I'm going to forget this? Thank you.

Comment: The MSDN Page link provided in the answer is for WSE - the problem with that is the attributes in httpRuntime element are different from today's attributes which are executionTimeout and maxRequestLength as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx), which makes me wonder how @user402186 implemented the solution provided if he is using WCF. Impossible no? In my case I had to add the element to both the client and server side to get this to work for me. I will move on to steaming asap though. Just curious is all.

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out, try using [Streaming Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx), here's some example code showing both sending and receiving (possibly) large amounts of data using streamed transfer.

Use a **binding** like this, notice the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` and `TranferMode` settings.

```
<binding name="Streaming_Binding" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"  
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed">
</binding>
```

Add some **service code**:

```
[OperationContract]
public Stream GetLargeFile()
{
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}

[OperationContract]
public void SendLargeFile(Stream stream)
{
    // Handle stream here - e.g. save to disk    
    ProcessTheStream(stream);

    // Close the stream when done processing it
    stream.Close();
}
```

And some **client code**:

```
public Stream GetLargeFile()
{
    var client = /* create proxy here */;
    try
    {
        var response = client.GetLargeFile();

        // All communication is now handled by the stream, 
        // thus we can close the proxy at this point
        client.Close();

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}

public void SendLargeFile(string path)
{
    var client = /* create proxy here */;
    client.SendLargeFile(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
}
```

Also, make sure you are not getting a timeout, a large file might take a while to transfer (the default receiveTimeout is 10 minutes though).

You can download Microsoft WCF/WF sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/) (top C# link is broken at the time of writing but other samples code seems ok).

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I sort of got your answer, but what i don't understand here, is that you are returning a stream from the service to the client. I want it the other way round, the client will be uploading large files to the server ..... or did i got your answer wrong?

Comment: Aha, sorry, missed that, well, it is more or less a matter of reversing the process. Added code to show that!

Comment: Correct! I changed the name to avoid future confusion.

Comment: samples link is broken as usual (not your fault)

Comment: @Veverke: Thanks, updated link although sample page still somewhat broken

Answer (score 5):

Have you had a look at using Streaming Transfer?

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   can send messages using either
>   buffered or streamed transfers. In the
>   default buffered-transfer mode, a
>   message must be completely delivered
>   before a receiver can read it. In
>   streaming transfer mode, the receiver
>   can begin to process the message
>   before it is completely delivered. The
>   streaming mode is useful when the
>   information that is passed is lengthy
>   and can be processed serially.
>   Streaming mode is also useful when the
>   message is too large to be entirely
>   buffered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

Comment: I am using "Streamed" as transfer mode. In my Server Web.config I have: messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"

Comment: In the above config I have transferMode="StreamedRequest", I tried that as well, but it didnt work either

Comment: You also need to modify your contracts to use Stream objects.

Comment: I am trying to add the transfer mode but in web.config file it giving the error.

Answer (score 2):

I'll echo what others have said and say that using a Streaming Transfer is the way to go when using Windows Communication Foundation. Below is an excellent guide that explains all of the steps in order to stream files over WCF. It's quite comprehensive and very informative.

Here it is: [Guide on Streaming Files over WCF](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/01/streaming-files-over-wcf.html).