# WCF Service returning 502 Http Code (The specified network name is no longer available.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a console application to send a file to my WCF Service, but my service is responding with 502 http code (Proxy Error - The specified network name is no longer available.) when I try to send files larger than 4MB. This code does not make sense to me, since he accepts files smaller than 4MB.

WCF Service is running under Windows 2003 Server, IIS 6 and the configuration file as the below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="FileUploadServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="False" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <!-- buffer: 64KB; max size: 64MB -->
            <binding name="FileUploadServiceBinding"
                    transferMode="Streamed"
                    messageEncoding="Mtom"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferSize="65536"
                    closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBehavior" name="MyProject.ServiceFileTransfer.FileUploadService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyProject.ServiceFileTransfer.IFileUploadService"
               bindingConfiguration="FileUploadServiceBinding">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Why a 502 Bad Gateway error is returned when files larger than 4mb are sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit is 4mb. You either need to split the file into smaler parts.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f6541134-2e08-4eb9-987b-2158fb99b403/

Or change MaxMessageLength

[Large Binary (byte[]) File transfer through WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030137/large-binary-byte-file-transfer-through-wcf)