# Increase ASP.NET 2.0 Web Services Timeout

Tags: asp.net, web-services, timeout, asmx

I need to increase ASP .NET 2.0 web service timeout value due to copy/hash 4GB file by web service call. I did following configurations.

```
Set proxy timeout=7200000
```

in client code

At client machine web.config file,compilation debug="false" httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="14400"

At server machine which host web service web.config file,

```
compilation debug="false"
httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="10800"
```

At server machine machine.config file

```
processModel responseDeadlockInterval="05:00:00" userName="XXX" password="XXX" autoConfig="true" webGarden="true" At server machine MetaBase.xml file AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed="1073741824" AspScriptTimeout=”10800”AspSessionTimeout=”60”ConnectionTimeout=”14400”
```

Server machine is on Internet. With above configuration, server machine web service log still has `Thread was being aborted exception` after around 2 minutes during file copy/hash operation. Why increasing timeout does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the maxAllowedContentLength setting in your Web Service web.config as suggested in this post [How do I upload large (> 25MB) files to a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998927/how-do-i-upload-large-25mb-files-to-a-web-service)